# Not able to append child in correct way

Tags: javascript, html

I have textarea and I want to append a paragraph tag, before I can get the value of textarea.

I am trying to do it with Javascript create element

```
var desc = document.createElement("p");
desc.innerHTML = description;
var abc = document.getElementById("textareaCode").appendChild(desc);
alert (abc);
 var comment = document.getElementById('textareaCode').value;
alert (comment);
```

This is the error message

[object HTMLParagraphElement]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A textarea does not have the `value` property. You can get what's between the tags by using `innerHTML`:

```js
var desc = document.createElement("p");
desc.innerHTML = 'blablabla';
var abc = document.getElementById("textareaCode").appendChild(desc);
var comment = document.getElementById('textareaCode').innerHTML;
alert (comment);
```

```html
<textarea id="textareaCode"></textarea>
```

**Note** as Victor Popescu commented, that even if natively the HTML attribute `value` doesn't exist for a textarea, the setter exists in javascript so you can dynamically change the content with `document.getElementById('textareaCode').value = 'test';` (but that won't add the attribute to the HTML, and more surprisingly won't update the DOM content, even if `innerHTML` will give you the right updated value).

About the rest of your problem, you can manipulate directly `innerHTML` to add text to existing one. But note that HTML tags will be rendered as text (`<` becomes `&lt;`, etc). Either you append an HTML object and it won't show in the textarea, either as text and it won't be treated as HTML:

```js
var description = 'blablabla';
document.getElementById('textareaCode').innerHTML += '<p>' + description + '</p>';
var comment = document.getElementById('textareaCode').innerHTML;
alert (comment);
```

```html
<textarea id="textareaCode">existing text</textarea>
```

Comment: I used append because I need another tag inside textarea. I have already written some text inside textarea and I want the content should be remaining and another P tag should be appended inside textarea. You code is appending but it removes the all content of textarea.

Comment: That's not right, you can't use value as a html attribute `<textarea value="">` but you can set/get the textarea value in javascript.(https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_textarea_value.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure this isn't working as expected? First you alert 'abc' which is an element. So the alert tells you that it's an element. After that you do alert(comment), which should be the alert you're looking for.

Comment: How can I get the code on alert like <p>some text</p>

Comment: @user3030404 try getting the innerHTML value. In your case replace alert (abc); with alert (abc.innerHTML);

Answer (score 0):

```js
var description ="hello world! love coding"; document.getElementById("textareaCode").value=description;
 var comment = document.getElementById('textareaCode').value;
alert (comment)
```

```html
<textarea id="textareaCode"></textarea/>
```

u cant append a html element to a textarea instead u can do it with  value !